# Change&Save an html file through a server side

Tags: python, client-server, aiohttp

I have an issue regard a html-file changing through server-side.
I'ill explain:
I am trying to build a Queue Management System and I wish to display a queue on the client-side.
It's should seems like that:
[image]

But the problem is that I do not know how to change html through the server.
I'm using python3 (aiohttp+asyncio) if it's important.

Answer (score 0):

edit: This question was misunderstood by me, look a the comment of JuiceFV to get an appropiate answer.

A simple example of a server that serves a webpage is like this:

```
from aiohttp import web
routes = web.RouteTableDef()

@routes.get('/')
async def hello(request):
    return web.Response(text="<html><body><h2>Hello, world</h2></body></html>", content_type="text/html")

app = web.Application()
app.add_routes(routes)
web.run_app(app)
```

It yields **Hello, world** at the client side.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I meant a little bit different thing. For example, when an user gets his token, it (token) has to be seen each user of the application, from their own client. Also I used templates (rendering the using jinja2), therefore I need to change my index.html through server. I found a solution with jinja2 (https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/)